# InstagramError(kind: invalidRequest, message: "This endpoint has been retired")

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, instagram-api

I'm using pod 'SwiftInstagram', '~> 1.0.6' for Instagram login and fetching user
This error is coming from fetching Instagram followers list.

```
private var api = Instagram.shared

func getUserFollowers (completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, InstagramUsersObject?, String?) -> Swift.Void) {
        api.userFollowers(success: { (users) in
            // success, got the user followers
            print(users)
            let followersList = self.createJSONObjectForInstagramUsers(data: users)
            let userList = Mapper<InstagramUsersObject>().map(JSONObject: followersList)
            print(followersList)
            completionHandler(true, userList, "")
        }) { (error) in
            // error while fetching user followers
           //InstagramError(kind: invalidRequest, message: "This endpoint has been retired")
            print(error)
            completionHandler(false, nil, error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could it be this?: https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/02/instagram-api-limit/

Comment: Instagram has deprecated /users/self/followed-by API from April 4, 2018.

Comment: Then this question is not related to programming and doesn't belong on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please understand there are 4 major changes using Instagram API.

1. Few endpoints are permanently deprecated with effect from 4th April
2. There is change API response in few cases.
3. Change in API rate limit from 30th March
4. No new app registration allowed

So presently error you are facing is related to the first issue, Please change your code to handle other 3 scenarios.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/

https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Answer (score 2):

As per [Instagram API changelog](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/) the /users endpoint has been suddenly deprecated (previously it was annunced that the deprecation would have occurred on July 31st). All the followers and relationship related informations were fetched through the /users endpoint. I suppose that every app or framework was using this endpoint to retrieve the followers and related information, as I'm not aware of any other method, and now it is no longer possible with any of the new Graph APIs.